# QGIS 3.10 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 136: invalid start byte

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, unicodedecodeerror, qswat

I'm a complete newbie to programming and QGIS. I'm working with a virtual machine.
If I start a new SWAT Projekt in QGIS, click on Delineate Watershed and load in the .tif file that I need I get the following error message(s):

```
2021-12-21T16:48:54     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):                   
File"C:/Users/heebt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QSWAT3_64\QSWAT\delineation.py", line 401,  in btnSetDEM                   self.addHillshade(demFile, root, demMapLayer, self._gv)                   
File"C:/Users/heebt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QSWAT3_64\QSWAT\delineation.py", line 424, in addHillshade      or line in proc:           
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode           (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)                 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 136: invalid start byte
```

What can I do?

Comment: Just a guess. Is there any non-english character in the file path?

Comment: no, unfortunately not..

Comment: The recommended way to proceed in these cases is to contact plugin authors and let them know about the issue. In that way, other users of the same plugin can benefit from your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my version of Windows 11 came without python so the only thing I had to do is install python...

On Pythons' website, I read that some Programs on Windows 11 might experience some issues with the newest versions of Python so for anyone else who might have the same problem in the future, just install the Long-term version of either Python 3.10 or 3.9. Works perfectly now.